# Shading reactor

Tags: reactor, project-reactor

I am trying to shade the reactor (https://github.com/reactor/reactor) and am running into an issue starting the event bus up. I am getting the following error. Any advice on shading this project would be greatly appreciated

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Dispatcher found for name 'threadPoolExecutor', it must be present in the configuration properties or being registered programmatically through this#setDispatcher(threadPoolExecutor, someDispatcher)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should also be a properties file in `META-INF/reactor/reactor-environment.properties`. Without this in the classpath you will see this error.

Comment: Thanks Jon, It's there but I think I see the problem, the shade plugin has shaded strings like PROPERTY_PREFIX_REACTOR - so instead of `PROPERTY_PREFIX_REACTOR = "reactor."
 it is PROPERTY_PREFIX_REACTOR = "foo.bar.shaded.reactor."`